# SVG circle scaling and moving on a round line

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am working on navigation for a customizer part of a form, in which the circular svg's are on a  horizontal line. If you are in step A (lest say from A-G), A increases in size. (Picture below - and I am really sorry for my pain skills).

[image]

Now, I've decided to go a little further, and make animation more 3D: instead of a horizontal line, I want the circles to be on a round line, where they will shrink in size, the further away from the current step they are (both on the left side and right side). Picture below:

[image]

Is there a way I can achive this using pure CSS, without JS? If so, any pointers are more than welcome. The only solution that comes to my mind, is to calculate each position of a circle, and move it on navigation change. However, this doesn't seem to be great idea - maybe there is easier way to achive this?

Comment: You could set a CSS transform on the circles and manipulate that on hover.

Comment: We need to see your actual code in order to be more helpful.